# Echoing an array PHP

Tags: php

I would like to echo the results of this array in a readable format "[id], [reason], how can I do that?

```
$s1 = "SELECT DISTINCT `id`, `reason` FROM wlp_$this->client.lu_unallocation_reasons";
        $m1 = $this->conn1->_execute($s1);
        while ($r1 = $this->conn1->_nextRow($m1)) {
            $reasons[] = array('id' => $r1['id'], 'reason' => $r1['reason']);
        }
```

Comment: try `print_r($reasons);`

Comment: Use print_r print_r($reasons); http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I am logging the array, not echoing it, so that would not work :(

Comment: In that case you can use `$arr_str = print_r($reasons, TRUE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a foreach loop.

```
foreach($reasons as $reason){
   echo "ID: ".$reason['id']."<br>";
   echo "Reason: ".$reason['reason']."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont need to save the reasons, you can output them in your loop directly:

```
echo $r1['id'],', ',$r1['reason'],'<br >';
```

For debug reasons just use `var_dump` to do this. If you want to make it more readable, add a `<pre></pre>` around it. You can also use `var_export` to echo valid php code.

1. http://php.net/var_dump
2. http://php.net/var_export

Answer (score 0):

You can use [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php): `print_r($reasons);` or simply loop through your array: `foreach($reasons as $reason) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

do this...

```
print_r($reasons);
```

print_r() displays information about a variable in a way that's readable by humans.

**If given an array, values will be presented in a format that shows keys and elements. **

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest print_r(). I would wrap it in `<pre>` tags to make it a bit easier to read:

```
<?php

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($reasons);
echo '</pre>';
```